# In JPA, why do pre-remove events do not trigger validation unless enabled via validation group property?

Tags: jpa, bean-validation, lifecycle

JPA delegates validation to the Bean Validation implementation during pre-persist and pre-update entity life-cycle events. But, pre-remove events do not trigger validation unless enabled via validation group property in persistence.xml. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess an entity does not need to be validated for default group once you decide to delete it. By specifying group for delete, validation will be executed.